# Android ImageView to display list of images

Tags: android, iphone, uiimageview, rotation, imageview

On my iPhone app I use a UIImageView to which I set an array of images. The imageView starts with the images "animating" (the view displays each image for a period of time and then shows the next one, etc). Is there any way to do this in android ImageView?

Comment: You are looking for an [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and schedule a TimerTask for repeated fixed-delay execution.

```
schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi were needed to do it exactly the same `ListView` and i found an amazing library...

Called AQuery, you can check [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading)

go to the [Delayed Image Loading](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading#Delay_Image_Loading)

Most of all enjoy this library it's amazing.